# Model not generated on creating a table in database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I created a table named **products** in postgresql

*create table products ( id int,... )*
    and restarted postgresql server
   How to generate its corresponding Model (Product.rb) in Rails? Is it possible ? 
 PS : I am a beginner to Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 1):

Don't create tables manually instead use `ActiveRecord::Migration`

For example:

`rails generate model product name:string description:string price:integer`

Rails automatically creates `id, created_at and updated_at` fields for you so you don't need to specify them while creating your model.

Then run `rake db:migrate` and your Products table will be created for you.

Comment: HI Rubysmith, Yeah I'm well aware of the above method, but why can't we create tables manually ? Is it not the right way ? Or it is not possible at all ? Thanks, Supraja

Comment: Rails does not take a schema first approach or database first approach to developing web applications. It uses migrations to map changes to the database. Schema first approaches are possible but it is not the right way.

Comment: Okay. So how to perform schema first approach ? Any idea / suggestion ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@kitsched/starting-a-ruby-on-rails-project-from-existing-data-7dda5044c85f#.5490f6ay4

Answer (score 0):

Models in rails are nothing but a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base, and by convention goes under app/models directory.

They are generally created using rails generate model command.

But you can also create them manually and place it under app/models directory.

Use the following in product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord:: Base

end
```